# Trouble returning the correct boolean value

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program to check a password. All 5 conditions must be true for the password to be valid. The problem I am having is if the entered password is long enough, the password is automatically valid even if the other conditions are not valid. I have tried changing many small things, but haven't been able to get it to check all the conditions. Any help is much appreciated!

```
public class Password
{
//Program main method
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String another = "y";
      while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
      {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
         String password = scan.nextLine();
      
      
      //Print output
         if (checkPassword(password))
         {
            System.out.println("Entered Password: " + password);
            System.out.println("Judgement: " + "Valid password");
            System.out.println("Re-run Program (y/n)? ");
            another = scan.next();
         }
         else 
         {
            System.out.println("Entered Password: " + password);
            System.out.println("Judgement: " + "Invalid password");
            System.out.println("Re-run Program (y/n)? ");
            another = scan.next();
         }
      }
   }
//
   public static boolean checkPassword(String password)
   {
      if(!minChars(password)) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (!onlyCharsAndDigits(password)) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (!minDigits(password)) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (!minLowerCase(password)) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (!minUpperCase(password)) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
   

//
   public static boolean minChars(String password)
   {
      if (password.length() > 8) {
      return true;
      }
      else {
      return false;
      }
   }

//method to test password has letters and digits or not
   public static boolean onlyCharsAndDigits(String password)
   {
      for(int i=0;i < password.length();i++)
      {
         if(!Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)))
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }


//method to test password has letters and digits or not
   public static boolean minDigits(String password)
   {
      int numberOfDigits = 0;
      for(int i=0;i < password.length();i++)
      {
         if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)));
         {
            numberOfDigits++;
         }
      }
      return numberOfDigits >= 3;
   }

//method to test password has letters and digits or not

   public static boolean minLowerCase(String password)
   {
      int numberOfLowerCase = 0;
      for(int i=0;i < password.length();i++)
      {
         if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i)));
         {
            numberOfLowerCase++;
         }
      }
      return numberOfLowerCase >= 3;
   }

//method to test password has letters and digits or not
   public static boolean minUpperCase(String password)
   {
      int numberOfUpperCase = 0;
      for(int i=0;i < password.length();i++)
      {
         if(!Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)));
         {
            numberOfUpperCase++;
         }
      }
      return numberOfUpperCase >= 3;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that your code will be much clearer by using the form `return password.length() > 8` whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Change all `else if` to `if` in the `checkPassword` method.

An `else if` branch will not be executed if any of the preceding branches are executed.

Your code can be simplified as

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String password) {
    return minChars(password) && onlyCharsAndDigits(password) 
        && minDigits(password) && minLowerCase(password) && minUpperCase(password);
}
```